# Get Data from JSON decode Using Pgp

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, json

So i have a function that checks for reference in my system which is like a pyramid, i want to display who you invited and who he or she invited too, im using this foreach loop to get all reference under a user id and save them in json. but im having problem listing or extrating the results using php.
here is my pup recursive function to find all children or an entered user.

```
    <?php  

include 'includes/connect.php';

 
$menu['Users'] =getChildren(2);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($menu); // check tree array
function getChildren($parent_id)
{
    $db=new mysqli('localhost','root','P=3h?9)Do#R@w2NQ','tobo'); //db
  $refs=$db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ref=$parent_id");
  $children = array();
  $i = 0;   
  foreach ($refs as $key => $downline) {
    $children[$i] = array();
    $children[$i]['fname'] = $downline['fname'];
    $children[$i]['downline'] =getChildren($downline['id']);
    $i++;
  } 
  return $children;
} 

$myJson = json_encode($menu);

$newJson = json_decode($myJson, true); ?>
```

it works fine and i get the following result:

```
    Array
(
    [Users] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [fname] => Andrey
                    [downline] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [fname] => Alisa
                                    [downline] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [fname] => Maxim
                                                    [downline] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [fname] => james
                                                                    [downline] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [fname] => Satori
                    [downline] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

my question is how can i get this result in a list using php so i can display the to the user as a list.

i tried to decode but im new to json so its still not usable by me. i hope you will be patient with my question structure, thank u very much